# What are the precise effects of rubies in weapons (why do the tooltips show a range)?

Tags: diablo-iii

I can't quite figure out the tooltip for a ruby when socketed in a weapon. I have a radiant ruby, which according to the in-game tooltip adds `+12-24` damage, but [according to the website adds 12 to the minimum damage and 12 to the maximum](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/radiant-ruby).

When I socket it in a weapon, it seems to indeed add 12 to each:

Before:

[image: unsocketed]

After:

[image: socketed]

So why does it show `+12-24`? Where did that 24 come from? Under what conditions, if any, will that ruby provide anything else instead of +12/+12?

Comment: I completely misunderstood this question. I am confused.

Comment: Technically, "+12" is within the range of "+12 - 24". That'll teach you to trust those sneaky NPC sales pitches!

Comment: @Wikwocket What's funny is, because of the backwards way things are calculated, your snarky comment and Emerica's deleted answer were basically right all along. The reason it's expressed as a range basically boils down to `because it's inclusive of all possible results given the wonky way +12 min/+12 max is actually calculated.`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Most of this answer refers to the way rubies displayed their effects prior to patch 1.0.3. I've left it intact because while Rubies no longer display a range, the behavior or applying *+Minimum Damage* before *+Maximum Damage* persists, and does occasionally cause some weirdness in exactly how much benefit a Ruby and other similar affixes provide.**

So, it's actually a lot more complicated than it first appears - it seems that the benefit of the Ruby is actually subject to a couple of bugs regarding how damage bonuses are calculated. The short version is that weapons with narrow damage ranges -  which are *usually* slower, and lower level weapons - tend to receive a slightly larger benefit from rubies. This in turn is what has caused the vast majority of testing, which tends to be done with low level gems on level 15-20 weapons to be so inconclusive - the effect I'm about to describe basically washes out at higher levels. This is because the calculation is... strange.

As an example, let's take a look at this axe, which provides a useful test case because it doesn't have any elemental damage on it. (Elemental damage is handled slightly differently, and more importantly, is applied *after* the addition of damage from the Ruby, so you need to calculate it back out before evaluating most weapons. Note however that flat +Min/+Max modifiers *are* applied at the same time as a ruby, and can be simply aggregated).

[image: Axe]

As you can see, the ruby brings the axes total damage from 13-22 to 23-34, a bonus of +10-+12. The reason is because when a Ruby is socketed, it works in the form of two separate modifiers, of +10 to minimum and maximum damage. The +minimum is applied first, taking our 13-22 axe up to 23-22 -- **BUT** since the max can't be lower than the min, we have to bump the minimum up to Min+1, or **24** damage. *Then*, after this, the +10 Max damage bonus is applied, bringing us to, you guessed it, 23-34.

This effect tends to get washed out on weapons with a large damage range, so it's typically not noticed at higher levels. If you'd like to see more of the math, including how this interacts with elemental damage, % damage modifiers, etc., I'd direct you to [this reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/uqap1/max_dps_perfect_rolls_for_every_weapon_type/c4xxrt1).

**The takeaway from this, for most players, is that you can evaluate the value of a ruby in most weapons simply by using the lower bound listed as a flat modifier. The only edge case is at very low levels with very slow weapons -  a circumstance in which a Ruby is *better than all other options no matter what, anyway.***

Comment: Though the gems still fail to list the gold combine cost, so they're still not infallible.

Comment: Another person testing the damage increase of rubies didn't observe the same dependency on the weapon's attack speed (see [this thread](http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showthread.php?831896)).

Comment: Do you have any proof? Like screenshots or something.

Comment: I thought rubies added 12-12 to one-handed weapons and 24-24 to two-handed

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock Yeah, I've done some further testing and can reproduce *similar*, but not identical results. The best result I can come to is that speed seems to matter, handedness does not, and that **rubies are totally broken.** (Hence, I haven't updated this, because I have nothing conclusive at this time.)

Comment: I did some testing with socketed items of different kinds and got some interesting results that seem to give creedence to the idea that rubies are either broken or by design alter slower weapons differently to faster ones. http://i.imgur.com/1HFjG.jpg

Comment: @Nimphious Thanks for that screenshot! It helped a lot to get this one solved.

Comment: Fascinating! This also explains why it's always `+X-2X` - because in the corner case of a weapon with a constant damage, it will indeed be `+X` to minimum and `+2X` to maximum.

Comment: Could you expand about how it all interacts with elemental damage, though? Because I look at @Nimphious brilliant list and can't understand how things are different when there's elemental damage.

Comment: @Oak As noted in the Reddit thread linked, Elemental damage works 'intuitively', adding the range as listed (as do bonuses from rings and amulets). It's just that Elemental damage is added *after* the bonus from the Ruby, so in order to apply this to Nimphious's data, you'll need to subtract the elemental damage modifiers first, then re-add them at the end.

Comment: According to the referenced Reddit thread the data is gathered directly from the Diablo III.exe binary. You can find the formulas by opening the binary with a text/hex editor.

Comment: And with 1.07 this is now really outdated since rubies now work how you would expect, adding some to min and some to max without any interaction between the two.

Answer (score 7):

<strike>Since the [website](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/radiant-ruby) reads `Weapon: +12 Minimum Damage, +12 Maximum Damage`, I suspect it is just an incorrect tooltip</strike>

Its likely that at one point during testing the gems increased the maximum damage by twice the minimum, however this probably got scaled back and the tooltip never updated

**EDIT:** This actually isn't correct.

Rubies provide a flat increase to some weapons, for others however, there is a range that  is based on weapon speed. See [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/69265/8462) for more details

Comment: Upon some further testing, this actually isn't correct. (See my answer).