# When should I switch from rubies to emeralds in weapons?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I socket my weapon with a Ruby or Emerald?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72286/should-i-socket-my-weapon-with-a-ruby-or-emerald)

At about level 20 you start getting weapons with slots. First it is way more powerful to insert a ruby for the +X damage.

Later as the weapon damage increases the benefit from rubies get less and it is way better to insert an emerald for the +X% critical hit damage.

Is there a rule or guideline how to determine the best point to switch instead of trying both gems?

I am not certain that this goes for every class, as I have only a high level Demonhunter.

Comment: How about this. You give info on your weapon, and the bonus on both damage bonuses. Basically, provide all the variables, and i can answer the question. I dont have Diablo3, but this question can be answered with simple math.

Comment: @ChaosPointDK The point of the question is not to apply specifically to him.  It's meant to answer it for *all* characters for everyone.  Regardless, it's a duplicate.