# How do Rubies scale in weapons?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the precise effects of rubies in weapons (why do the tooltips show a range)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69250/what-are-the-precise-effects-of-rubies-in-weapons-why-do-the-tooltips-show-a-ra)

I read on here that Rubies socketed into weapons scale their max damage bonus based off of the weapon's speed, but the answer did not specify how the scaling is done to determine how much the damage bonus should actually be.

Original answer: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/69265

I'm asking because I'm in the process of creating a dps spreadsheet and I'd like to get my calculations as accurate as possible.

Comment: My original answer isn't *100%* correct. I've done some further testing, but can come to no further conclusion than that: **Rubies are wierd** and that **speed seems to matter**, but it doesn't apply in any consistent or uniform way that I can see.

Comment: try this question, it compairs rubies & emeralds in weapons, but has a good example of the math: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72286/should-i-socket-my-weapon-with-a-ruby-or-emerald

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on your original answer. I'll just have to leave it alone in the spreadsheet for now or keep trying to figure it out I guess. If I come up with anything useful, I'll toss it up here.

Comment: @Ryala one short term option for your spreadsheet is to calculate two DPS values, one based on *minimum* Ruby effectiveness (i.e. `12-12`), and one based on *maximum* Ruby effectiveness (i.e. `12-24`). You should be able to compare those two numbers and get a feel for the range of difference involved.

Comment: @Ryala just in case you didn't mark it as a favorite, I thought I'd ping you to inform you that the exact mechanic has been figured out. I've edited my answer to the other question.

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is some confusion regarding the rubies. Blizzard lists them as giving a flat bonus (which is true in most cases) despite the damage range which you can see in the tool tip in game. Attack speed seem not to modify the bonus of the rubies in most cases.

Let's say you have a 1-hand axe with 17-31 damage with an empty socket and no other bonuses. This axe would give you a DPS of 31.2 since axes allow base speed of 1.3 attacks per second:

> Mean damage (D) = (17+31)/2 = 24
>   Attack speed (S) = 1.3
>   DPS = D • S = 31.2

A [perfect ruby](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/perfect-ruby) gives a flat +11 damage as you can see in Blizzard's item database. In game, you will see a bonus of 11-22 damage but for now you can consider this wrong for all rubies. Just take the minimum damage as flat bonus.

With a perfect ruby the increased DPS of your weapon would be 45.5:

> Perfect ruby damage bonus (B) = 11
>   DPS = (D + B) • S = 45.5

Sometimes you may observe strange increases of your damage which differ from the flat bonus the rubies should give and which may be linked to the attack speed. But with this formula you will have at least a good approximation of the DPS after socketing.

Comment: That is originally how I went about the formula, but as the spreadsheet grew, so did the small inaccuracies to the point where the dps number it spits out is off by up to several percent (500ish dps in one case) and that's with only a small base of 3 testers. I do know there are more errors than just the rubies, but the ruby issue is a part of it and I think I've found the answers/formulas for the other parts. Perhaps once I get the other fixes in, the rubies being the only inaccuracy won't be as bad.

Comment: Please let me know when you find the correct formulas. I'm currently developing a weapon calculator for http://xraymeta.com and I've also some inaccuracy issues.